# What does this woman say in Chinese? (From the new Daredevil tv show)

Tags: translation, mandarin

I was watching the new Daredevil show and noticed this bit.  I was hoping somebody might be able to explain what the elderly lady is saying...Thanks.

Here is the clip:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJlop7mkvt4&feature=youtu.be

Here is a second clip of her:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS_pwIum-3o&feature=youtu.be

Comment: 2: 这个人是cuku跟zhizhi，还是把你们弄成大傻瓜 dont'get the middle part.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. 有些人的手，永遠是染著他人的鮮血，會冷的。

Some people's hands are always bathed* in the blood of others. They get cold.

> 2. 這些人，他是偷貨給自己的，還是把你們弄成大傻瓜？

Did these people steal the products for themselves, or did they turn you guys into idiots?

*`染 = to dye`, but, in the context `染著(someone's)鮮血`, the more accurate translation would be `bathed in the blood`.

By the way, in my opinion, this woman's pronunciation is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

1, 是人的手，永远是人啊，他人的先驱(身驱）。

It is human's hand, It is always human, Another people's body.

2， 这个人他是出货给自已，还是把你们弄成大傻瓜？

The man he shipped goods to himself, or to fool(make) you into idiot?

Excuse my English.